# How to stop YouTube suggesting videos while I'm watching one

Tags: youtube

While watching a YouTube video a little white suggestion bar will slide over the top right corner of the screen, suggesting I watch something else. How do I stop this? I know it goes away after a few seconds but some videos you'll have the bar come across ten times and it's pretty annoying.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. You click on your profile, go into settings > playback and performance and then uncheck show in-video info cards.